# Single Sign On in Moodle with external login form

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on, moodle

I'm developing a moodle site where I have to use an external service for authenticating users. This SSO service should be the only form of authentication.

The provider of the external service requires me to do use their login form on their server so I have to disable the moodle login form.

I have looked at the various authentication plugins but none of them seems to do exactly what I need them to do.

Thus far I think this is what I'm going to do:

1. Change the login/index.php file so it does nothing but redirect the user to the external login form.
2. The SSO service heads back to a new page on my Moodle server that confirms the credentials supplied.
3. All relevant user data is collected from a SOAP webservice connected to the SSO service.
4. If the (unique) username provided by the SSO service exists in the mdl_users table the row is updated with the relevant user data.
5. If the username does not exist a new user is generated automatically
   The user is then logged in to the Moodle site and headed to their front page.

This is my first time working with Moodle so I have a few questions:

1. How can I create a new user automatically? Is it enough just to add a new entry to mdl_users?
2. How do I sign a user in?
3. Can I make this sort of functionality as an authentication plugin or do I need to make a hack in the login/index.php file?
4. How do I disable the no longer needed parts of Moodle's own user management (i.e. password reset, user info fields that are collected from the SOAP service etc.)?

I really hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Call create_user_record() (line 4008 of lib/moodlelib.php in master branch). This does the insert into mdl_user but also performs a bunch of checks and calls other functions to take care of dependencies, event triggers and so on. This function is called automatically by authenticate_user_login() (see below) if the user being authenticated doesn't already exist.
2. This involves calling authenticate_user_login() (line 4378 of lib/moodlelib.php) followed by complete_user_login() (line 4577 of lib/moodlelib.php).
3. This can all be achieved by creating an authentication plugin, and you should be able to find everything you need to know at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins, including links to example code and a suggested template.
4. You can lock user profile fields via your auth plugin and you can actually set a custom/external password reset page via the admin interface at /admin/settings.php?section=manageauths.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I just have one more question: How can I completely disable Moodle's own login page and redirect all login reuests to the external SSO service?

Comment: You can override the default login page by setting `$CFG->alternateloginurl` via the admin interface at `/admin/settings.php?section=manageauths`.

Comment: You are really helpful :) I have another problem now. When I try to call the authenticate_user_login and complete_user_login functions from a separate page nothing happens. Not even an error message. When I instead link back to moodle/login/index.php (as recommended in the admin panel) and insert the relevant values for username and password in $_POST I get stuck in an infinite loop of redirects between the SSO and the moodle/login/index.php file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have developer level debugging turned on for your Moodle site? If not, go to Site administration -> Development -> Debugging, set 'Debug messages' to 'DEVELOPER', check the 'Display debug messages' check box and save the settings. This should give you some fairly detailed error/debug messages when things don't work.

Comment: this is not working for moodle 3.3. Can anyone suggest how to do this in moodle 3.3.